# Crystal Reports 2008 Report Header causing duplicate records in Details of sub report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am modifying a report in Crystal Reports 2008, fixing a sum issue, and duplication of records. The report contains a single sub report.

I have corrected the sum issue.

I was seemingly able to correct the duplication of records by removing the only grouping set up within the sub report. I have noticed that if I display the Report Header (currently no elements are in the Report Header) within the sub report, records are duplicated again. I am hoping to place labels in the Report Header.

Do you know what would cause duplication of records simply by displaying an empty Report Header in the sub report? What am I missing? I don't see the relevance between displaying an empty report header and duplication of records.

The sub report lives in a Group Footer on the main report, and Group Expert shows 2 groupings on the main report.  I'm new to Crystal Reports, and if I did not provide you with enough information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: displaying the header willnot create duplication...check whether there are any fields in header that are supressed so that when fields are present you query is changing and records are duplicated also you can check the query before display of report header and after display of report header

Comment: Siva- Thank you for your response.
I have confirmed that there are no fields in the header. 
Would you explain how to check the query in various areas of the report? I'm familiar with the Show SQL Query command, but am unsure as to how to check the query elsewhere/runtime.
Thank you.

Comment: Show sql query is the only command...compare the queries before and after the report header

Comment: Thanks Siva. Will do.